# Metodo que recibe datetime nulleable, cambiar formato a MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime, null

tengo una pregunta..
Tengo un metodo que recibe varias fechas en formato datetime (dd/mm/yyyy)

Algo asi

```
public ActionResult Reports(DateTime? FechaInicio, DateTime? FechaFin, DateTime? IptSemana, DateTime? IptDia)
```

Al momento de ejecutar el SP envio los parametros de la siguiente forma:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaInicio;  //? (object)DBNull.Value : FechaFin);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaFin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaFin;  //? (object)DBNull.Value : FechaFin);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaSemana", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = IptSemana;//  ? (object)DBNull.Value : IptSemana);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaDia", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = IptDia;//  ? (object)DBNull.Value : IptDia);
```

Como puedo cambiar el formato de fecha a MM/dd/yyyy si me marca un error de que el datetime es nulleable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para los objetos que aceptan valores nulos, puedes acceder a su valor desde la propiedad "value"

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaInicio.value;
```

Pero lo mejor acá es hacer una condición y asignarles un valor si están nulos, por ejemplo

```
if (FechaInicio == null) { FechaInicio = DateTime.Now; }
```

Comment: Necesito mandarle null, o el valor que trae por que el sp si es null omite el filtro...

Answer (score 1):

Preguntas con `.HasValue` si tiene valor, luego sobre el valor devuelves el formato

```
  dt.HasValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : dt.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

EDITADO, uso completo.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("FechaInicio", FechaInicio.HasValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : FechaInicio.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
```

Comment: algo asi?cmd.Parameters.Add("@FechaInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaInicio.HasValue ? (object)DBNull.Value : FechaInicio.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: No, alli te muestro

Comment: Se puede simplificar usando cmd.Parameters.Add("FechaInicio", FechaInicio ?? (object)DBNull.Value); Aplicas el coalescing operator

Comment: O inclusive puedes hacer cmd.Parameters.Add("FechaInicio", FechaInicio?.Value);